# Show if orbit is discrete, the orbit is closed.

Tags: general-topology

Given $\beta <$ the isometry group $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that if an orbit $\beta_x$ is discrete, then $\beta_x$ is closed.

I am just looking for some feedback and critique of my attempt at a proof.

Proof:

If $\beta_x$ is discrete then there exists some $y \in \beta_x$ such that for $r>0$, $B(y,r) \cap \beta_x = \{y\}$. Let $y' \in \beta_x^{c}$ (the complement of $\beta_x$) in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Since $\mathbb{R}^2$ is Hausdorff, for $r>0$ there exists $B(y',r) \cap \beta_x = \emptyset$, thus $\beta_x^{c}$ is open and $\beta_x$ is closed.

Comment: Your proof doesn't uses the fact that $\beta_x$ isn't an arbitrary discrete subset of the plane but an orbit. I think this condition is important. Just consider the discrete set $\{(\frac{1}{n},0)\}_{n \in \mathbb N}$ which isn't closed.

Comment: I see. That makes sense since the set you described is in fact a discrete subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ that is not closed since it does not contain $0$. I will think about this some more. Thank you.

Comment: It seems that perhaps I could use the fact that an orbit is discrete if and only if every ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$ contains at most finitely many elements.

Comment: I could give you a hint but I'm sure about that you'll find the solution without my help too.

Comment: Indeed, If you've proved that fact, you have almost nothing to do.